# Optimization – Rearranging items of a specific type?

Tags: optimization

Optimization – Rearranging items of a specific type?
Here’s a little optimization problem for a personal project I’m working on: so imagine you have many boxes of an item, and within each box, you know that the items must be shipped to various locations.

Example:

> Box 1: 1000 items, 500 to location A, 500 to location B.
>
> Box 2: 1000 items, 500 to location A, 500 to location B.

I want to be able to rearrange the items such that I can ship as many full boxes as I can to one destination. For instance, in the example above, I would be able to rearrange the items such that new_box 1 has 1000 items to location A, and 1000 to location B.

Now you can imagine that this perfect rearrangement case will not always occur. What if I had:

> Box 1: 1000 items, 500 to location A, 300 to location B, 200 to location C.
>
> Box 2: 1000 items, 500 to location A, 500 to location B.

Then, I would want to (a) optimize the number of full boxes to one destination, & (b) minimize the number of *different* locations in every other box. For instance, having 3 boxes each with 2 different destinations would be better than having 3 boxes each with 3 different destinations. The optimum rearrangement of the second example above would be:

> New_box_1: 1000 items, 1000 to location A.
>
> New_box_2: 1000 items, 800 to location B and 200 to location C.

My question is: **How would I handle this situation for arbitrary number of boxes and arbitrary number of destinations per box?** For the sake of the problem, let’s start with assuming that each box has the same number of items.

What I’m thinking right now is to take a greedy approach:

1. Go down the line for each subsequent box and keep a running sum of the destinations and the number of items that will be shipped to it.
2. If any of these sum to a value that is greater than the box capacity, place these items in their own box.
3. Then, take the highest number of items to one destination that is remaining, call this “x”, take the value (box capacity – x), (call this “y”), and find the value of the number of items to one destination that is both ABOVE “y” and the closest to “y”.
4. Then, place “x” items to the first destination and “y items to the second destination in another box, and repeat.

Any other suggestions, or insights? Thanks so much.

Comment: I swear at first I thought this was a P=NP joke/gag question. Turned out quite interesting.

Comment: Sounds like a variation on the knapsack problem....

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean? There can be any initial distribution of destinations in a box, I think.

Comment: E.g., are there any restrictions to moving elements from one box to another? If not, we can pour all the elements in one big bag and redistribute them to boxes, without caring at all for the initial setup.

Comment: Also, which is better: Two boxes with three destinations each, or one box with two, and one with four destinations?

Comment: No restrictions. Yeah, that is what I was thinking... Just take all the boxes, sum up total number of items that go to each destination, and then reallocate?

Comment: I suppose those two situations would be treated _equally_. Let's go ahead and say that if two configurations have the same number of fully-filled boxes (including 0 fully-filled boxes), then the box with the "total number" of destinations wins. i.e. two boxes with three destinations each would have 6 total destinations, and one box with two and one with four would also have 2 + 4 = 6 destinations each.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple 1d bin-packing problem. The problem is a box with 1000 items at most. Then you can use a bin-packing algorithm like best-fit, first-fit or so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, bin-packing tries to minimize the number of bins used in the packing, correct? I believe the problem I have described tries to minimize the number of different objects in each bin... Is it still a valid reduction? Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore, you will always need to use the same number of bins no matter what, because you are simply trying to rearrange the items.

Comment: Well, ideally, I want a box to have items that *all* go to one destination. All of the items... are the same type of item, they just go to different destinations.

In my second example, I have 2000 total items initially (2 bins, each with 1000); no matter how I rearrange them, I will always have 2 bins. That's my point -- I'm not minimizing the bins, but rather, I want to minimize the number of total destinations within a bin.

Comment: Hmm, can you elaborate a little bit more? You can group the items by destination (items that go to different destinations are essentially my different "types" of objects), but you want to minimize the number of types of objects _within_ _each_ bin, not overall. In my mind, binpacking minimizes the total number of bins used _overall_. Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks.